# How do I pass a value from my SplitView controller to a map?

Tags: swift, storyboard

So I have a SplitView controller and the cells have cities and states (ex: Dalllas, TX, etc) when I select a cell I know how to go to a detail view using a segue. But, how do I send data another UIViewController containing a map?

After I’ve created my segue my code associated with the SplitView looks like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let cell:UITableViewCell = sender as! UITableViewCell

        let destinationViewController:ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
              // “cell.textLable” is where the value is passed from the SplitView
if let text = cell.textLabel!.text {

            let incedent = LocationIncedent(sName: text)
            destinationViewController.detailString = "Lat:" + String(stringInterpolationSegment: incedent.incLat) + " Long:" + String(stringInterpolationSegment: incedent.incLong)
```

DestinationViewController is where the label accepts displays the value. However, how do I get the values sent to a map instead of a label.  Moreover, I need to pass latitude and longitude coordinates to a CLLocationCoordinate2D method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You create a property on the `destinationViewController` for each object you want to pass and assign this property in the segue method.

In your destinationViewController's `viewDidLoad()` you can user the data signed to these properties to populate a MKMapView...